# Java Login page button does not work

Tags: java, database, database-connection

I'm working on a login page using java application, trying to connect it to an access database I created, just want a simple select query to check if the entered username and password are valid, I get no errors when executed, but the button does not work, any ideas?

Here is the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Login {

   Connection con;
   Statement st;
   ResultSet rs;

   JFrame f = new JFrame("User Login");
   JLabel l = new JLabel("Username");
   JLabel ll= new JLabel("Password");
   JTextField t = new JTextField(10);
   JTextField t1 = new JTextField(10);
   JButton b = new JButton("Login");

   public Login()
   {
       connect();
       frame();
   }

   public void connect()
  {
       try
       {
       String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
       Class.forName(driver);
       String db = "jdbc:odbc:db1";
       con = DriverManager.getConnection(db);
       st = con.createStatement();

       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {

       }
   }

   public void frame()
   {
       f.setSize(600,400);
       f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       f.setVisible(true);

       JPanel p = new JPanel();
       p.add(l);
       p.add(t);
       p.add(ll);
       p.add(t1);
       p.add(b);
       f.add(p);

     b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
       public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
      {
         try{
        String user = t.getText().trim();
       String pass = t1.getText().trim();

     String sql = "select username, password from Users where username =                 
'"+user+"' and password= '"+pass+"'";
              rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

            int count = 0;
           while(rs.next())
          {
             count = count +1;
        }

      if (count == 1)
     {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User Found, Access     
Granted!");
              }
             else if (count > 1)
                    {
                       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Duplicate User, 
Access Denied!");
                      }
             else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User not Found!");
           }

         }
        catch(Exception ex)
       {}
  }
});

}


public static void main(String [] args)
{
    new Login ();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean "the button does not work"? The event never gets fired or the fact that the code within the event produces no results for you?

If you are just going to use a record count to determine whether or not a particular User/Password exists then I would like to suggest you do it this way:

```
int count = 0;
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) AS rCount FROM Users WHERE username = '" + user + "' AND password = '" + pass + "';");
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    count = rs.getInt("rCount");
}
rs.close();
stmt.close();

if (count != 0) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User Found, Access Granted!");
}
```

However, you could very well do it this way as well:

```
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT username, password FROM Users WHERE username = '" + user + "' AND password = '" + pass + "';");
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
String un = "";
String up = "";
while (rs.next()) {
    un = rs.getString("username");
    up = rs.getString("password");
    // or any other table fields you want...
}
rs.close();
stmt.close();

if (!un.equals("") && !up.equals("")) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User Found, Access Granted!");
}
```

You might want to also take a look at using the [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) library. It works pretty good with MS Access.